Landsat 7 image appears yellow (wrong) when creating true colour composite
I create a true colour composite of a 2010 Landsat 7 image (LE07_L2SR_176109_20101107_20200910_02_T2_SR_B*) from bands 3/2/1. I've created it both as a virtual raster in QGIS and created a composite in gdal. What is white/grey ice/snow is appearing as a totally unrealistic yellow in default QGIS settings.Any ideas whats the problem is and what settings I can adjust to get to appear true colour?
I'm having a similar problem with other Landsat 7 images that I've not having with Landsat 8. QGIS seems capable of applying good setting with L8 but not 7? Surely I don't have to spend ages manually trying to get the right settings on every L7 image.

